# I get an error whenever I try to convert from hex to Ascii

Tags: python, decode

So here is my code

```
import codecs
m = 61626374667b7273345f69735f61773373306d337
print(m.decode("hex"))
```

And this is the error that I get, I'm not sure if it is a problem within the syntax or I didn't use the library well.

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: I'm not sure what your Python is doing.  Don't you need "" around your string?  `m = .......` should also be giving you an error.

Comment: Maybe try something like this https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-a-string-from-hex-to-ascii-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is from python2.

If you want to decode a string using decode from codecs you need to use:

```
import codecs

string = "68656c6c6f" #Your string here, between quotation mark
binary_str = codecs.decode(string, "hex")
print(str(binary_str,'utf-8'))
```

This will still won't work because you provided an hex string with an ODD number of letters, and every ascii letter is represented by 2 hex digits, so recheck your string.

(The code is from [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/hex-to-ascii-python/))

Comment: What do you mean by "This method is from python2."? You're using Python 3 syntax, just like OP.

Comment: Using simply decode on a hex string is a method that worked previously in version 2 of python but won't work on python 3, which will raise the error that is in the question.